# TortoiseGit/Windows10 - Long File Name Support?

Tags: windows-10, filenames, tortoisegit

When TortoiseGit was built, did it have an application manifest with 'longPathAware=TRUE'? Does the Window10 implmentation of TortoiseGit really support long file names?

(I don't want to build TortoiseGit from source code, I am interested in an answer to this question as it applies to the precompiled version of TortoiseGit for Windows 10.)

[reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd]

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseGit is not yet long path aware as some dependencies are not (as of 2.12.0).

Just having set `longPathAware=TRUE` won't help, also all buffers need to be long enough.

See https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1017